# How do I extract little-endian unsigned short from long pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a long pointer value that points to a 20 byte header structure followed by a larger array. Dec(57987104)=Hex(0374D020). All the values are stored little endian. 1400 when swapped is 0014 which in decimal is 20.

[image]

The question here is how do I get the first value which is a 2 byte unsigned short. I have a C++ dll to convert this for me. I'm running Windows 10.

```
GetCellData_API unsigned short __stdcall getUnsignedShort(unsigned long ptr) 
{
    unsigned long *p = &ptr;
    unsigned short ret = *p;
    return ret;
}
```

But when I call this from VBA using `Debug.Print getUnsignedShort(57987104)` I get 30008 when it should be 20.

I might need to do an endian swap but I'm not sure how to incorporate this from [CodeGuru: How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values?](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?292902-C-General-How-do-I-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values)

```
inline void endian_swap(unsigned short& x)
{
    x = (x >> 8) |
        (x << 8);
}
```

How do I extract little endian unsigned short from long pointer?

Comment: The second unsigned short value happens to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd be inclined to write your interface function in terms of a general template function that describes the operation:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint>

// Code for the general case
// you'll be amazed at the compiler's optimiser
template<class Integral>
auto extract_be(const std::uint8_t* buffer)
{
    using accumulator_type = std::make_unsigned_t<Integral>;

    auto acc = accumulator_type(0);
    auto count = sizeof(Integral);

    while(count--)
    {
        acc |= accumulator_type(*buffer++) << (8 * count);
    }

    return Integral(acc);
}



GetCellData_API unsigned short __stdcall getUnsignedShort(std::uintptr_t ptr) 
{
    return extract_be<std::uint16_t>(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(ptr));
}
```

As you can see from the [demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/5jBLuW), the compiler does all the hard work for you.

Note that since we know the size of the data, I have used the sized integer types exported from `<cstdint>` in case this code needs to be ported to another platform.

EDIT:

Just realised that your data is actually LITTLE ENDIAN :)

```
template<class Integral>
auto extract_le(const std::uint8_t* buffer)
{
    using accumulator_type = std::make_unsigned_t<Integral>;

    auto acc = accumulator_type(0);
    constexpr auto size = sizeof(Integral);

    for(std::size_t count = 0 ; count < size ; ++count)
    {
        acc |= accumulator_type(*buffer++) << (8 * count);
    }

    return Integral(acc);
}


GetCellData_API unsigned short __stdcall getUnsignedShort(std::uintptr_t ptr) 
{
    return extract_le<std::uint16_t>(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(ptr));
}
```

Comment: Will this be easy to convert to get the long values for the rest of the header? (still reading/understanding/testing)

Comment: @D_Bester "All the values are stored big endian." I think you meant to say "little-endian"

Comment: With your new version, I'm getting back -19957. Still no good.

Comment: @D_Bester can you post an MCVE on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ and share it with me to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @D_Bester because it's working for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b82f5e3a7b627ca

Comment: I found the reason for my problem. The long pointer was generated in a different process. So even though I had the right pointer, I had the wrong virtual memory area. I fixed it by using ReadProcessMemory called from VB.net.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say youre pointing with pulong pulong[6] you are pointing 6 sixth member of the table

`unsigned short psh*;
     unsigned char  puchar*
     unsigend char ptable[4];
     ZeroMemory(ptable,4);
     puchar[3]=((char *)( &pulong[6]))[0];
     puchar[2]=((char *)( &pulong[6]))[1];
     puchar[1]=((char *)( &pulong[6]))[2];
     puchar[0]=((char *)( &pulong[6]))[3];
     psh=(unsigned short *) puchar;
     //first one
     psh[0];
     //second one
     psh[1];`


THis was what was in my mind while mistaking me

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. It doesn't even compile. I don't see how to get my pointer into your code and it doesn't output any decimal value. So this seems not relevant to me.

Comment: If this relates to `endian_swap` then you've missed my question and this answer should be deleted. I don't even know whether `endian_swap` is relevant to my question or not. I think it isn't.

Comment: I appreciate your time though.